What is the max value we can use for `--rpc-max-connections ` flag of substrate node template?
I am using substrate node template. We know it comes with many flag . I want to know specifics about --rpc-max-conections . We know that default is 100 but i want to know is there any maximum limitation for this connection.

Each of these connections will occupy resources, if used. This means that basically your hardware is the limit, bandwidth, CPU power etc.
